# Library Java Project to Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, tomcat7, war

I am attempting to make this java application web accessible:
http://ge.tt/4jnFeFy/v/0

I have imported it successfully into eclipse and followed this guide to convert it to a web project:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-project-to-web-project-in-eclipse/

I have then exported the project as a war file which you can see here if interested:
http://ge.tt/48bpeFy/v/0

I put the war file into my webapps directory and it self-extracted to a new folder where I should be able to access it. However when I go to localhost/library I get a 404 error.

```
HTTP Status 404 - /library/

type Status report

message /library/

description The requested resource (/library/) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
```

I downloaded the sample war from here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/sample/ and put that in my webapps folder and had no problem accessing it from localhost/sample.

Why is the java application I converted to a web project not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of reason's why your war won't work as expected.

- The link you followed is just to convert a java app project to web app project in Eclipse. And it doesn't guarantee that it'll work in an Application Server. i.e., what you've done is just made the Eclipse to recognize that project as Dynamic Web Application.
- Do you have any servlets or jsp or html pages inside that war? Without it, Web App may not work.
- Did you check the WEB-INF/web.xml which might not the properly configured.
- Or your project might not have any welcome page. So, you got 404.

If possible, upload your deployed war to tell the exact reason.

Comment: I uploaded the war for you to download in the original question. How might the web.xml file need to be configured? What are my first steps to getting it to run on the web if it works in eclipse just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded the Library project.It ought to be a desktop app rather than a web app.If you want to convert it to a web app,you should write servlet or jsp yourself.Have you write servlet or jsp or other compnent after you convert it to a web project?If not,it is normal to get a 404 error.

Comment: I do need to convert it to a web app. Do you have any suggested tutorials on how to convert a desktop app to a web application? I am just confused on how to tackle this.